# Can't retrieve data from my database for my tkinter GUI

Tags: python, database, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

It will not allow me to access my hints from my database, an error comes up.

Code:

```
def do_question(self):
self.func1()
#myGlobal + 1
if myGlobal >5:
    import MathsvadersReal

SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tblQuestion'
cursor = Databaseconnector.SELECT(SQL)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
random_row = random.choice(rows)

print random_row.QuestionID, random_row.Question, random_row.Hint, random_row.A1, random_row.A2, random_row.A3, random_row.A4, random_row.CorrectAnswer

# create welcome label
self.label1 = Tkinter.Label(self, bg ='yellow', text = (random_row.Question))
self.label1.grid(row = 0, column = 6, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'E')

self.label111 = Tkinter.Label(self, bg ='red', text = (random_row.QuestionID))
self.label111.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 4, sticky = 'W')
```

Hint Code:

```
  def homepage_link(self):
    SQL = 'SELECT Hint FROM tblQuestion WHERE QuestionID = %s' % self.label111
    cursor = Databaseconnector.SELECT(SQL)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Hint", rows[0]['Hint'])
```

ERROR:

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The IndexError indicates that `fetchall()` isn't returning any rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the string representation of the widget instead of the `text` option. The first line of `homepage_link` should be:

```
SQL = 'SELECT Hint FROM tblQuestion WHERE QuestionID = %s' % self.label111['text']
```

Comment: when I change that I get a different error: TypeError: row indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @SmithJr Use `rows[0][0]` instead of `rows[0]['Hint']`.

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @SmithJr Then that is a problem of another part of your code. Note that you get this error if you do something like `"mystring"['foo']`, but since you are using integers as indices, th problem cannot be there.